# How to import specific files from a scoped node package?

Tags: node.js, npm, import, scope, node-modules

How can I import subdirectories or files from imported packages that are scoped?

For example I perfectly **can do**:

`import array from "lodash/array"`.

But as soon as my package is scoped the `array.js` file (or `array/index.js`) becomes becomes unavailable, as the following **will not work**:

`import array from "@myscope/lodash/array"`

Comment: It should work. You can check @angular/common/http for example. The reason why it doesn't work is specific to your fork. You could build it incorrectly or else.

Comment: @estus thanks for hinting it out. It's not about my containing project structure or configuration though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [@estus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus)' hint I inspected @angular/common/http (https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/common/http) and tried to replicate its file structure and `package` to understand what's going on.

Apparently You can only deep import from scoped packages with a specific file structure, which is skipping the `dist` or any other kind of directory that holds Your bundled files. You need to directly have the directory or file You wish to deep import in the scoped package.

**Not working example:**

`node_modules/@angular/common/dist/http/index.js`

Here you **will not** be able to do `import http from "@angular/common/http"` no matter how you setup your `package.json`s. This is the structure I bundled my scoped package into though.

**Working example:**

`node_modules/@angular/common/http/index.js`

Here you **will** be able to do `import http from "@angular/common/http"`. You don't even need a `node_modules/@angular/common/http/package.json` for that, a `node_modules/@angular/common/package.json` is sufficient.